# when i send a link to my website on any social media it redirects to another site

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to figure out why my site redirects to another site. earlier the issue existed on Google listings too but I was able to solve that.

i have tried changing the records that fixed the google listings issue.

Comment: seems your website has been hacked. Check your code